# How do I add an entry to the end of the line in bash

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, sudo

I have a sudoers file that I'm trying to add /usr/sbin/ifconfig at the end of a line. So what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
devops  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ifconfig, /usr/sbin/ethtool, /usr/sbin/hwclock
```

I tried to run:

```
echo "/usr/sbin/ifconfig" | ssh $i "tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/dev_ops"
```

but it only creates another line with it but I don't need duplicate lines.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/ifconfig` exists ... in the middle of the existing line; what exactly is the starting point and ending point? and are you ssh'ing as root?

Comment: Use `sudoedit` and add the line yourself.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that there is a line in `/etc/sudoers.d/dev_ops` that provides NOPASSWD access to `/usr/sbin/ifconfig` to devops, consider this:

```
grep -q '^devops.*NOPASSWD:.*/usr/sbin/ifconfig' /etc/sudoers.d/dev_ops || 
  ed -s /etc/sudoers.d/dev_ops <<< $'/^devops.*NOPASSWD:/ s!$!, /usr/sbin/ifconfig!\nw\nq'
```

The intent is: look for a string beginning with "devops" that then contains the string "NOPASSWD:" followed at some point in that same line by the string "/usr/sbin/ifconfig". If that string does *not* exist in the file, then use `ed` to find the (assumed) line that starts with "devops" and is followed by the string "NOPASSWD:"; on that line, search and replace the end-of-the-line with ", /usr/sbin/ifconfig", then save & quit.  This will fail if there is no line in `/etc/sudoers.d/dev_ops` that matches the regular expression "^devops.*NOPASSWD:" -- you'll get a `?` from `ed` and no changes will be applied.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much!:)

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget the check mark :)

Comment: @user5352090 to show appreciation click the ✓